# C# - Decoding server response (How many positions in a string is 1 octet?)

Tags: c#, sockets, hex

I'm communicating with a server via Socket. Where I send commands and receive responses from that server.

To decode the response from the server, I'm using the following:

> string returndata = BitConverter.ToString (bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead)
> .Replace ("-", "");

**Complete server response:**

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

From that response, I need to extract information, in which the manual says the following:

> From Octet 052 to 055: Active power phase A (IEEE floating point - 754
> in 32 bits)

Assuming that 1 octet is 2 positions (I'm not sure). Then from Octet 52 to 55 the result would be: **0D8936C9**. Which I believe to be a hexadecimal number. Converting to floating point: 8.45.

Is that it or am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: what about using `BitConverter.ToSingle` with `bytesToRead` directly  with pointing 52 as position? (eventualy you have to tak subarray from 52 to 55 and revert it and use ToSingle - if endianness is involved)

Comment: and it's rather A8996840 or 9968400D(if instructions says that octets are 0 based) .. https://dotnetfiddle.net/xxz2wS ... and octet is 1 byte

Comment: I get different results.  What order are the bytes?  float num = BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] { 0x0D, 0x89, 0x36, 0xC9 },0);

Comment: Hi Selvin. How many positions is 1 byte? I will test what you posted.

Comment: Selvin, the BitConverter.ToSingle solved my problem. Thanks.